# grep -r and searching in whole disk

Tags: linux

```
grep -r xxx" /*
grep: /dev/log: No such device or address
grep: /dev/dvd: No medium found
grep: /dev/cdrw: No medium found
grep: /dev/cdrom: No medium found
```

but it takes more then 2 hours without results. If I use `grep -r "xxx" /etc` then I get results. How can I search in whole disk?

Comment: `/*` is the path to *every* file on the system. How about just replacing `/*` with `/`. `/` is a directory as much as `/etc`.

Answer (score 5):

Using `grep -r` blindly on `/` is not a good idea. Several directories (e.g. `/dev` and `/proc`) contain special files that should not be accessed in an uncontrolled manner - doing so could just flood your screen with errors, have you wait until the end of the world or even crash your system.

You need to use [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) to prevent the search from descending into those directories and leave special files alone:

- Use explicit negated `-path` options:

  ```
  find / -maxdepth 2 -type f ! -path '/proc/*' ! -path '/dev/*' -exec grep "xxx" {} +
  ```
- Use the `-prune` option:

  ```
  find / -maxdepth 2 -path '/proc' -prune -o -path '/dev' -prune -o -type f -exec grep "xxx" {} +
  ```
- Use the `-xdev` option to avoid descending to other filesystems completely:

  ```
  find / -maxdepth 2 -xdev -type f -exec grep "xxx" {} +
  ```

`-type f` will only let through regular files. You can use as many `-path` and/or `-prune` options as you need to fine-tune the output of `find`.

Also note the use of the `-exec ... +` variation of `-exec` that calls `grep` with multiple files, rather than launch a separate `grep` process for every single one of them.
Alternatively, you could use [`xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) to call `grep`:

```
find / -maxdepth 2 -xdev -type f -print0 | xargs -r -0 grep "xxx"
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9507304/507519) is an older answer of mine to a related question...

Comment: Specifically, the recursive search of `/` is quite possibly getting to `/dev/tty` and reading from that, so the `grep` is reading from the terminal without the user realizing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search the whole disk, use find

```
find / -type f -exec grep "xxx" {} /dev/null \;
```

The /dev/null in the answer allows grep to print the file name with the match.

In order to avoid running a new grep process for each file, I wrote a [Perl version of grep](https://github.com/dadinck/snippets/blob/master/pgrep) (pipegrep) which reads file names from stdin. You would run it like

```
find / -type f -print | pipegrep "string to find"
```

The code is here:

```
#!/bin/perl

$pat = shift || die "I won't search for nothing";
while (<STDIN>) {
    chomp;
    if(-f $_ && open(IN, $_)) {
        @matches = grep(/$pat/, <IN>);
        close IN;
        for $match (@matches) {
           print $_, ": ", $match;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. `find ... -exec ... ;` is a *very* bad idea; it will launch a new `grep` process for each matching file. 2. The reason `grep ... /dev/null` prints out the file name is because you force `grep` into multi-file mode by adding `/dev/null` as a second file. `grep -H` is the proper way to do this...

Comment: @thkala `grep -H` is not the proper way. the `-H` switch is a non-standard GNU extension see [HP-UX](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c02254191/c02254191.pdf) and [AIX](http://publib16.boulder.ibm.com/pseries/en_US/cmds/aixcmds2/aixcmds2.pdf)

Comment: If you are doing this as a one time command, make sure to "nice" it. If you will be doing this often, generate a proper script with "find2perl"